# Proving the number of solutions in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let *F* be a finite field containing $q$ elements.  Let $a \in F$ be nonzero.  If *n* divides $q -1$ prove that $x^n - a = 0$ has either *n* solutions in *F* or no solutions in *F*.

I am unsure of how to begin this problem.  I know that since $q -1$ is the order of the cyclic group of the nonzero elements of *F* under multiplication, *n* divides the order of this group, but I am having a hard time seeing how it is useful.  Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: You say "if $n$ divides $p^n-1$..." However, the exponent of $p$ and the degree of the equation do not have to be the same, right? You can say "if $k$ divides $p^n-1$, then $x^k-1$ has $n$ solutions or no solutions in F...." Right?

Comment: You are correct.  I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the equation $x^n-a$ has a root $c\in F$.

Let $k=\frac{q-1}{n}$, and let $\beta$ be any generator for the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of $F$.

I claim that $\;c,\; c\cdot \beta^k, \;c \cdot \beta^{2k} , \;c \cdot \beta^{3k}, ..., \;c \cdot \beta^{(n-1)k}$  are all roots of the equation $x^n-a$, and that these roots are all distinct.

Indeed, whenever $0 \leq i \leq n-1$, we have that $$\big(c \cdot \beta^{ik}\big)^n = c^n \cdot \beta^{i(q-1)} =c^n \cdot 1 = a$$ where the second equality follows because $\beta$ has order $q-1$.

The reason that all of the elements $\{c \cdot \beta^{ik}\}_{0\leq i\leq n-1}$ are distinct is that if $0\leq i\leq j\leq n-1$, then $c \cdot \beta^{ik} = c \cdot \beta^{jk}$ implies that $\beta^{(j-i)k}=1$, which in turn implies that $i=j\;$ (because $\beta^k$ has order $n$ in $F^{\times}$).

Hence we have proved that if a solution to the equation "$x^n-a=0$" exists, then $n$ distinct solutions exist, which is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: Why can you assume a root exists?  For example, $x^2 - 2 = 0$ has no roots in $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: My argument is not saying that roots necessarily have to exist. It is merely considering the nontrivial case wherein a root actually exists.